# ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAI' from 'openai'

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

After the latest OpenAI deprecations in early Jan this year, I'm trying to convert from the older API calls to the newer ones. (openai==0.28.0 to 1.10.0)

After switching to the new functions I always get one error: ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAI' from 'openai'.

I'm working on an AWS EC2 instance, and I've tried to re-install the openai package, and upgrade it.

None of these fixes worked.

CODE:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

def openai_call(content):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
               model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
               messages=[
                 {
                 "role": "user",
                 "content": f"{content}"
                 }
               ],
               temperature=1,
               max_tokens=256,
               top_p=1,
               frequency_penalty=0,
               presence_penalty=0)
    return response.choices[0].message.content
```

ERROR (IN AWS LOGS):

```
Feb 01 18:14:33 ip-172-31-39-220 gunicorn[1641]:   File "/home/ubuntu/code_src/app.py", line 9, in <module>
Feb 01 18:14:33 ip-172-31-39-220 gunicorn[1641]:     import utils
Feb 01 18:14:33 ip-172-31-39-220 gunicorn[1641]:   File "/home/ubuntu/code_src/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
Feb 01 18:14:33 ip-172-31-39-220 gunicorn[1641]:     from openai import OpenAI
Feb 01 18:14:33 ip-172-31-39-220 gunicorn[1641]: ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAI' from 'openai' (/home/ubuntu/code_src/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/__init__.py
```

I tried to re-install and upgrade the packages, my current openai version is 1.10.0, but still it doesn't seem to work.

Attempt 1:
`pip install --upgrade openai==1.10.0`
Attempt 2:
`pip uninstall openai`
`pip install openai==1.10.0`

None of this seems to work. When I run it on a python interpreter shell with version 3.10.12, it works, along with the functions. When I try it on my files on the flask (gunicorn) server, it stops working. Does anyone know why?

Please let me know how I can fix it.